# How to reduce space between two columns in column chart using amcharts 4

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular10, amcharts4, column-chart

**I'm using Amchart 4 In Angular 10 and want to reduce space between two columns.**

I have tried so many ways but didn't solve this issue

Could you please someone help me with how to reduce those spaces between columns.

is there any elegant solution?

```
    let chart = am4core.create("authorisedChartDiv", am4charts.XYChart);
    chart.data = chartData;

    // Modify chart's colors
    chart.colors.list = [
        am4core.color("#1297e0"),
        am4core.color("#5ad146")
    ];

    var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
        categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "country";
        categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
        categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 100;
        categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;

        chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

    // Create series
    var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
    series.dataFields.valueY = "visits";
    series.dataFields.categoryX = "country";
    series.columns.template.tooltipText = "{categoryX}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";
    series.columns.template.fillOpacity = .8;
    series.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(20);

    var columnTemplate = series.columns.template;
    columnTemplate.strokeWidth = 1;
    columnTemplate.strokeOpacity = 0;
```

========
**See attached screenshot for more understanding**
[image]

```js
this.browserOnly(() => {
  am4core.useTheme(am4themes_material);
  am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

  let chart = am4core.create("authorisedChartDiv", am4charts.XYChart);
  chart.data = chartData;

  // Modify chart's colors
  chart.colors.list = [
    am4core.color("#1297e0"),
    am4core.color("#5ad146")
  ];

  var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
  categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "country";
  categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
  categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 100;
  categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;

  chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

  // Create series
  var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
  series.dataFields.valueY = "visits";
  series.dataFields.categoryX = "country";
  series.columns.template.tooltipText = "{categoryX}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";
  series.columns.template.fillOpacity = .8;
  series.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(20);

  var columnTemplate = series.columns.template;
  columnTemplate.strokeWidth = 1;
  columnTemplate.strokeOpacity = 0;

  // Add distinctive colors for each column using adapter
  series.columns.template.adapter.add("fill", (fill, target) => {
    return chart.colors.getIndex(target.dataItem.index);
  });
```

```css
#authorisedChartDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div id="authorisedChartDiv"></div>
```

Comment: What is the square width in the xAxis? 100 per each?

Comment: That auto set as per chartdata

Answer (score 0):

I guess this parameter are the key:

```
categoryAxis.renderer.cellStartLocation = 0.2
categoryAxis.renderer.cellEndLocation = 0.8
```

More info at: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/managing-width-and-spacing-of-column-series/

Comment: The above solution is to increase the inner radius size. If I have to increase 100% then column width will be increased.

Comment: It seems that the best solution is to reduce the chart width, and then increase the cell width. I didn´t find the correct parameter.